# Finitary monads on $\operatorname{Set}$ are substitution monoids. Finitary monads on $\operatorname{Set}_*$ are...?

Tags: ct.category-theory, operads, monads

$\DeclareMathOperator\Fin{Fin}\DeclareMathOperator\Lan{Lan}\DeclareMathOperator\Set{Set}$

> The present question is intimately related to [another question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/361969/substitution-structure-on-pointed-sets).

It is well known that the category of functors $\Fin \to \Set$ is equivalent to the category of finitary endofunctors $\Set \to \Set$; in this equivalence, finitary monads correspond to what are called *substitution monoids* on $[\Fin,\Set]$, i.e., to monoids with respect to the monoidal structure
$$
F \diamond G = m\mapsto \int^n Fn \times G^{*n}m \tag{$\star$}
$$ where $G^{*n}$ is the functor
$$
m \mapsto \int^{p_1,\dotsc, p_n} Gp_1 \times \dotsb \times Gp_n \times \Fin(\sum p_i, m).
$$
More precisely, the equivalence $[\Set,\Set]_{\omega} \cong [\Fin,\Set]$ can be promoted to a monoidal equivalence, and composition of endofunctors corresponds to substitution of presheaves in the following sense: let $J : \Fin \to \Set$ be the inclusion functor, then
$$
\Lan_J(F\diamond G) \cong \Lan_JF \circ \Lan_JG \tag{$\heartsuit$}
$$
and 
$$
(S\circ T) J \cong SJ \diamond TJ\tag{$\clubsuit$}
$$ for two finitary endofunctors $S,T : \Set \to \Set$. (Kan extending along $J$ and precomposing an endofunctor of $\Set$ with $J$ is what defines the equivalence.)

> I would like to prove the same exact theorem, replacing everywhere the cartesian category of sets with the monoidal category of *pointed* sets and smash product, but I keep failing.

The equivalence of categories
$$
[\Fin_*,\Set_*]\cong [\Set_*,\Set_*]
$$ remains true; and this equivalence must induce an equivalence between the category of finitary monads on pointed sets, and the category of suitable "pointed substitution" monoids, that are obtained from the iterated convolution on $[\Fin_*,\Set_*]$ as
$$
F\diamond' G = m \mapsto \int^n Fn \land G^{*n}m
$$ where $\land$ is the smash product, and $G^{*n}$ iterates the convolution on $[\Fin_*, \Set_*]$ induced by coproduct on domain, and smash on codomain:
$$
G^{*n}m = \int^{p_1,\dotsc,p_n} Gp_1 \land \dotsb\land Gp_n \land \Fin_*(\bigvee p_i, m)
$$ where $\bigvee p_i$ is the coproduct of pointed sets, joining all sets along their basepoint.

This would be the perfect equivalent of $(\star)$.

However, trying to prove the isomorphisms $(\heartsuit)$, $(\clubsuit)$, I find that it is not true that $\Lan_J(F\diamond G) \cong \Lan_JF \circ \Lan_JG$. I am starting to suspect that the generalisation is false as I have stated it, or that it is true in a more fine-tuned sense.

So, I kindly ask for your help:

> To what kind of monoids on $[\Fin_*,\Set_*]$ do finitary monads on pointed sets correspond?

**Edit**: I am led to believe this construction is not a particular instance of an [enriched Lawvere theory](http://www.tac.mta.ca/tac/volumes/6/n7/6-07abs.html), because in that framework a theory isn't what it is in mine:

- for Power, if $\mathcal V$ is a locally finitely presentable base of enrichment, a theory is an identity on objects functor $\mathcal V_\omega ^{op}\to \mathcal L$ from the subcategory of finitely presentable objects to $\mathcal L$ strictly preserving cotensors; if $\mathcal V = \Set_*$ with smash product, cotensors in $\mathcal V^{op}$ are tensors in $\mathcal V$, thus smash products.
- Instead, for me, a theory is a bijective-on-objects functor $\Fin_* \to \mathcal L$ that sends **coproduct** into smash product (or even a more general monoidal structure on $\mathcal L$).

Or at least, this is what I was led to believe trying to back-engineer the equivalence between finitary monads and Lawvere theories in the case of pointed sets.

Comment: Could it be the case that the equivalence works out in the $\mathrm{Set}_*$-enriched setting, giving a correspondence between $\mathrm{Set}_*$-enriched cartesian operads (or substitution monoids) and finitary $\mathrm{Set}_*$-monads on $\mathrm{Set}_*$? It looks like your setting is one in which sets are being consistently replaced with pointed sets, which seems suggestive of the setting for [enriched Lawvere theories](http://www.tac.mta.ca/tac/volumes/6/n7/n7.pdf). But perhaps there's an obvious reason this doesn't work out.

Comment: Set is Ind(Fin). Is Set$_*$ Ind(Fin$_*$)?

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე Yes, it is.

Comment: @varkor I will address your question tomorrow. Thanks for the attention :) Power's enriched Lawvere theories framework isn't exactly what it's needed here. Because you would have to take the monoidal structure given by smash on Fin_* too

Comment: @varkor I edited the question!

Comment: Interesting. Your theories are a little unusual, as they no longer look like a class of categories equipped with specified structure and generators, as in the traditional setting. If you haven't checked already, it would be worth comparing your setting to that of [Bourke & Garner's](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1805.04346.pdf), which establishes theory–monad correspondences in a great level of generality (potentially at the cost of some massaging to check your definitions align with theirs).

Comment: A distinctive feature of algebraic theories is that they are monoidal functors (in the case of classical Lawvere theories, cartesian). These correspond in turn to _promonoidal_ promonads on the associated arity. Is it the case that if an arity ${\cal A} \hookrightarrow {\cal E}$ is chosen to be monoidal (i.e., $\cal E$ is monoidal, e.g. the base of enrichment, and $\cal A$ is $\otimes$-closed), the $\cal A$-nervous monads must preserve this structure (thus, bestowing theories or the associated promonads with monoidality)?

Comment: It's unclear to me whether or not this is true: the definitions are very abstract, so it's difficult to get an intuition without explicitly working through the example. I notice that Bourke & Garner do not seem to give any examples in this vein, but it's not clear whether this is a deliberate omission. I personally would be interested to know the outcome if you do work through it.

Comment: It seems to me if  you want this to work, as you use the monoidal structure on pointed sets, you everything to be enriched in pointed sets. It means that you should restrict to $Set_*$-enriched functor, which are exactly the functor preserving the $0$-objects. Once you impose this restriction everything should work.

Answer (score 3):

Rather than checking to see if that is a substitution monoid, I think you might have an easier time using Rory Lucyshyn-Wright’s notion of a *eleutheric system of arities*, seen [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/1511.02920). It’s a relatively straightforward condition to check, with several equivalent statements.

Edit: To give a (very brief) description of how this works out: a monoidal subcategory of $\mathcal{V}$ is a symmetric monoidal subcategory $j:\mathcal{J} \to \mathcal{V}$, and a $\mathcal{J}$-ary Lawvere theory is a $\mathcal{V}$-category with a bijective-on-objects, power-preserving functor $\mathcal{J} \to \mathcal{T}$. A system of arities is *eleutheric* if for every $T: \mathcal{J} \to \mathcal{V}$, the left Kan extension $Lan_jT$ exists and is preserved by $\mathcal{V}(J,-), J \in \mathcal{J}$. This ends up being just enough to ensure that every $\mathcal{J}$-ary theory induces a free $\mathcal{T}$-algebra monad on $\mathcal{V}$.